# Java: Get classpath of another application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, classpath, classloader

Let's I have single application server (e.g. Jboss or WebLogic).
And I have two java ee applications (`web1.ear`, `web2.ear`) deployed on this AS.
Can I get classpath (or ClassLoader) of `web1.ear` from `web2.ear`.
Or they have same classloader?

Comment: As already stated your question is implementation specific. In JBoss (at least prior to JBoss 7) you could for example turn off classpath isolation so that all deployed applications were put in the same classloader - with the dependency hell that it brings along. Not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

No, by default those are isolated and that is on purpose. You can however take advantage of *shared libraries* that are available across most implementations of Java EE application servers. There you can define which JAR files are available to all apps deployed in a given domain.